# registers with the verification email , but when submitted insert double data

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

still continue the project which I've posted . a bit of trouble on registering with a verification email . currently running normally: registers the verification email, sents to the email destination. but I see there are two inserts with the same data (as submitted) in the database. Is there anything wrong with my script ?

this my controllers

```
function submit() {

    $_POST['dob'] = $_POST['year'].'-'.$_POST['month'].'-'.$_POST['day'];

    $firstname = $this->input->post('firstname');
    $lastname = $this->input->post('lastname');     
    $password = $this->input->post('password');
    $email = $this->input->post('email');
    $dob = $this->input->post('dob');
    $jkl = $this->input->post('jkl');   
    $lastlogin = $this->input->post('lastlogin');       

    $data = array(
        'firstname' => $firstname,
        'lastname' => $lastname,
        'password' => $password,
        'email' => $email,  
        'dob' => $dob,
        'jkl' => $jkl,
        'lastlogin' => $lastlogin,
        'active' => 0
    );

    $this->m_register->add_account($data);  
    $id = $this->m_register->add_account($data);

    $encrypted_id = md5($id);

    $this->load->library('email');

    $config = Array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
            'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
            'smtp_port' => 465,
            'smtp_user' => '*******@*****.com ',
            'smtp_pass' => '**********',
            'mailtype'  => 'html', 
            'charset' => 'utf-8',
            'wordwrap' => TRUE
        );      

           $this->load->library('email', $config);
           $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");
           $email_setting  = array('mailtype'=>'html');
           $this->email->initialize($email_setting);
           $this->email->from('*****@******.COM', 'RRR');
           $this->email->to($email);
           $this->email->subject('Confirmation Email');
           $this->email->message("WELCOME TO RRRR <br><p></p>Hallo $firstname $lastname <br><br><br><p>Terimakasih telah melakuan registrasi dengan:<br><br><p>
                       Username   = $email<p>
                       Password   = $password
                       <br><br>
                       <p>
                       untuk memverifikasi akun silahkan klik tautan dibawah ini</p><br><br>"
                       .site_url("login/register/verification/$encrypted_id")."
                       <br><br><br>
                       <p></p><br>

                       <p>Thanks</p>Admin ");


    if($this->email->send())
    {
    $data = array ( 'isi' => 'login/vsuccess');
            $this->load->view('layout/wrapper',$data);
    }else
    {
    $data = array ( 'isi' => 'login/vgagal');
            $this->load->view('layout/wrapper',$data);
    }


}
```

this my models

```
    function add_account($data){
        $this->load->database();
        $this->db->insert('user',$data);
        return  mysql_insert_id();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$this->m_register->add_account($data);  
$id = $this->m_register->add_account($data);
```

Check these two lines in your code, remove:

> $this->m_register->add_account($data);

And it will work.

Answer (score 2):

I don't fully understand the question, but have you noticed that you seem to insert data into your db twice?

```
$this->m_register->add_account($data);  
$id = $this->m_register->add_account($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are calling ad_account() twice.

```
$this->m_register->add_account($data);  
$id = $this->m_register->add_account($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->m_register->add_account($data);  
$id = $this->m_register->add_account($data);
```

Obviously, you insert $data to your database 2 times :)

Answer (score 1):

`$this->m_register->add_account($data);` calls the `add_account()` function in your `m_register` model. With `$id = $this->m_register->add_account($data);` you call it the second time, but you also catch the returned data. This should be the reason why you see the two inserts inside your database.

Deleting the first calling, and leaving just `$id = $this->m_register->add_account($data);`, should solve the problem.

I suggest adding form validation in your controller, where you could use a callback function for **email** in order to check if the email already exists in your table of users. This way a user cannot register twice with the same email.